# Synchronous files, delete the same data

Tags: c++, linux, file, synchronization

I have two files
A.txt

> 1
>  2
>  3

B.txt

> 1
>  2
>  3
>  4

I want to delete those data that appear in both A.txt and B.txt.
So the output should be:
C.txt

> 4

How to do this by c++ or linux machine?

Comment: `sort a.txt b.txt |uniq -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could archive this by doing below steps:

1 load A.txt int setA

```
std::set<std::string> setA;
```

2 load B.txt into setB

```
std::set<std::string> setB;
```

3 get the interation of setA and setB to setC

```
setC = set_intersection(setA.begin(), setA.end(),
                        setB.begin(), setB.end(),
                        setC);
```

4 Get rid of common data in setA

```
std::set<std::string> setDA;
set_difference(setA.begin(), setA.end(),
               setC.begin(), setC.end(),
               setDA);

// write content of setDA back to file A
```

5 Do the same thing for setB and write back to file B

Comment: A follow up question. How to read data to a set string? I know some simple command such as string temp; getline(Filehd,temp); But can I read the whole file into a set of string?

Comment: If you know getline, then you could insert each line into set.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

comm -3 a.txt b.txt

-3 is used for suppress the lines that appears in the both files.